Disable Email Register form
Disable Email Register form account.
I want my customers to sign up with an account and password but without email
Wordpress allow this ?

Not out of the box, I don't think. Some discussion here says it's OK for users to not have an email address, and it sounds like you can code that up yourself or some third party user registration forms support it too (but I can't recommend one)

Out-of-the-box, WordPress requires an email for the user. Theortically, you can circumvent that as long as you're populating the wp_users.user_email field in the db with some value.  However, that's very tricky because WP's default process will check the value with is_email() and email_exists().  You'd need to circumvent more than just the reg process.  It would be difficult to then manage editing the user information in the admin because that same default WP validation would still run.  So is it possible?  Theoretically yes; but in practical application, no - it's darn near impossible.
